# How to compare one value in a table with a list of other values in another table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have two tables:

```
a = {customer1:1234, customer2:3456, customer3:4567, customer4:3456}
b = {2345, 1234, 3456, 6789}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to compare the tables for a match. If no, then that value gets deleted. I am unable to find a way to do one to many compare against the values.

Please can you advise on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare both tables element-wise using loops.

Please read the Lua reference.

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.4
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5

simple example

```
local a = {1, 2, 3}

for k, v in pairs(a) do

  print(v)
end
```

Just replace the print with something else. For example another loop  that iterates over a second table. Using two nested loops allows you to compare each element of one table to all elements of another table. You can do whatever you want!

Please note that

```
a = {customer1:1234}
```

will cause a script error. Replace `:` by `=`

Comment: The solution you are suggesting would lead to `#a` iterations of b and `#b` iterations of a though

Comment: I know. As I said, it's a simple example. If I give him a complete optimized solution he will just copy and not learn a thing.

Comment: Thank You @Piglet, ... Will use your advice here and see if I can solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove values from both tables, I would take the following approach:

1. Iterate `a` and add it's values to a set `s_a`
2. Iterate `b`. If a value is in `s_a`, add it to a set `s_b`, if not remove it from `b`.
3. (optionally) `s_a = nil; collectgarbage()` to free some memory
4. Iterate `a` and remove values that you don't find in `s_b`

My implementation:

```
local s_a, s_b, iter_b = {}, {}, ipairs(b)
--starting with b because ipairs is a bit cheaper than pairs if done right
for k,v in iter_b do
  s_b[v]=true;
end
for k,v in pairs(a) do
  if s_b[v] then
    s_a[v]=true
  else
    a[k]=nil
  end
end
s_b = nil; collectgarbage()
for k,v in iter_b do
  if not s_a[v] then b[k] = nil
end
```

Comment: what do you mean with ipairs is a bit cheaper than pairs?

Comment: That was kind of a mistake, but not really. I just remembered it a bit wrong; Since ipairs returns a stateless iterator, it can be used on more than one loop, saving the cost of creating a new closure, but that doesn't apply in this case unless you do something like `local iter = ipairs(b)`. I'll edit it in a moment.